# Porque o dataScroller do primefaces para de buscar os registros?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2, primefaces-3.5

Meu xhtml está assim:

```
<p:dataScroller  ajax="true" id="listaDiarios" 
    chunkSize="3"  lazy="true"
    value="#{managedBeanUsuario.lazyRegistrosDiarios}"
    columnClasses="first-letter-page-diary,second-letter-page-diary"
    var="registro">
```

O load fiz da seguinte forma:

```
    LazyDataModel registros = new LazyDataModel() {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4742720028771554420L;
       @Override
       public List<RegistroDiario> load(int first, int pageSize,
          String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder,
          Map<String, Object> filters) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          System.out.println("entrei load "+ first);
          System.out.println("entrei size "+ pageSize); 
          System.out.println("qnt linhas "+ this.getRowCount()); 

          return RegistroDiarioDao.getAllLastRegistroDiarioVelho(first);

   }
};
```

E na DAO o método esta assim:

```
 public static ArrayList getAllLastRegistroDiarioVelho(int inicio) {

     EntityManager em = HibernateManageFactory.getFactory() 
        .createEntityManager();

     Query query = em.createQuery(
        "select u from RegistroDiario u order by u.dtRegistro desc",
        RegistroDiario.class);
query.setMaxResults(3); 
query.setFirstResult(inicio);
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

ArrayList<RegistroDiario> registrosDiarios = (ArrayList<RegistroDiario>) query.getResultList();

em.close();
return registrosDiarios;
}
```

Ele trás os registros, até ai tudo bem. Eu quero que ele traga sempre de 3 em 3, na primeira vez ele trás 3, quando desse o a barra de rolagem, ele trás mais 3 e depois ele para de ir buscar mais registros. Sendo que eu tenho muito mais que 6 registros no banco.

Não sei se estou fazendo certo ou errado, por isso queria a ajuda de vocês, quero que ele traga todos os registros do banco, porém indo buscando de 3 em 3

Answer (score 0):

É necessário fornecer o total de resultados a serem paginados para a `LazyDataModel`.

Como encontrado na documentação da versão 3.5:

> In addition to load method, totalRowCount needs to be provided so that paginator can display itself
>   according to the logical number of rows to display.

Execute uma query que conte o total de resultados e defina esse total como o `totalRowCount` da `LazyDataModel`. Algo como:

```java
// ...
int totalRegistrosDiarios = RegistroDiarioDAO.getTotalLastRegistrosDiariosVelhos();
registros.setRowCount(totalRegistrosDiarios);
// ...
```